# How to print paper in landscape mode by using vue-html-to-paper?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a problem to print in landscape by using vue-html-to-paper.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html-to-paper

Can someone show me the correct way?
Below are my folder and code:-

**plugins/main.js**

```
import VueHtmlToPaper from 'vue-html-to-paper'
const options = {
  name: '_blank',
  specs: [
    'fullscreen=yes',
    'titlebar=yes',
    'scrollbars=yes'
  ],
  "styles": [
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    '~/assets/css/landscape.css'
  ],
  timeout: 1000,
  autoClose: true,
  windowTitle: window.document.title,
}
Vue.use(VueHtmlToPaper, options);
```

I have no idea how to link the **landscape.css** in **plugins/main.js**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmpSr.png)**

assets/css/landscape.css**

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: landscape
    }
}
```

I want to print in **landscape** mode.